# Lazy load data bound list inside TabControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a TabControl with three tabs, each containing a DataGrid bound to a list of data.
The model behind the view is setup with lazy loaded properties.

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding FirstList}" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" Binding="{Binding Property1}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2" Binding="{Binding Property2}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SecondList}" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" Binding="{Binding Property1}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2" Binding="{Binding Property2}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ThirdList}" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" Binding="{Binding Property1}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2" Binding="{Binding Property2}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

My intention was that each list should be loaded only when clicking on the relevant tab. However, I end up loading all lists initially.

Is there any way to lazy load bindings for each TabItem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had that problem, too, and ended up adding a "Loaded" Property to the datasources that i bound to the `IsSelected` property of the TabItems, and that way lazy-loaded the data. Thinking about it, maybe using Datatemplates would have worked, too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! 

This would indeed solve the problem, but somehow I feel that there should be a way to do this properly...

Comment: Yes, it's really not a clean solution. Another idea would be to apply the binding from code-behind when the tab selection changes. At least that wouldn't require modifying the model, and the plumbing code would stay in the UI.